# Фрагмент создается несколько раз в PagerAdapter

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Есть `MainActivity` в нем есть фрагменты (`DrawerMenu`), в одном из них есть раздел Истории, который содержит еще 4 фрагмента подкрепляю через `ViewPagerAdapter` (табы). Так вот после очистки памяти на Kit Kat, `MainActivity` пересоздается вместе со всем остальным добром. Если юзать только 1 таб то вроде все хорошо, но после того как проюзать всю прогу несколько раз, то в логах выводится нечто подобное:

```
Create MainActivity
Create HsitoryFragment
Create PopularFragment
Create PopularFragment
Create PopularFragment
Create PopularFragment
Create PopularFragment
Create PopularFragment
Create PopularFragment
Create PopularFragment
Create PopularFragment
Create PopularFragment
```

В DrawerMenu у фрагментов используется .replace(), так же проверяю на создание по тегу. По всей видимости это проблема с табами, но вопрос в том как исправить ситуацию?

### MainActivity

**onSaveInstanceState**

```
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, "fragment" + sharedPreferences.getInt("FRAGMENT", 0), myFragment);
}
```

**onCreate**

```
  if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        setFragment(sharedPreferences.getInt("FRAGMENT", 0));
    } else {
        myFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragment(
                savedInstanceState, "fragment" + sharedPreferences.getInt("FRAGMENT", 0));
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment,    myFragment).commit();
    }
```

**Вызов Fragment (DrawerMenu)**

```
 public void setFragment(int position) {

    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);

    if(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("fragment" + position) != null) {
        myFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("fragment" + position);
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment, myFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        return;
    }else {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:                    
                myFragment = new FragmentHistory();
                break;
            case 1:
                myFragment = new FragmentGroup();
                break;
            case 2:
                myFragment = new FragmentDialogs();
                break;
            case 3:
                myFragment = new FragmentUsers();
                break;
        }
        sharedPreferences.edit().putInt("FRAGMENT", position).apply();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment, myFragment, "fragment" + position);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

### FragmentHistory

**public void setupTubs()**

```
 public void setupTabs() {
    tabsHistoryViewPagerAdapter = new   TabsHistoryViewPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager(), titles, tabNumber);
    pager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter(tabsHistoryViewPagerAdapter);
    tabs = (SlidingTabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabs.setDistributeEvenly(false);
    tabs.setViewPager(pager);
 }
```

### TabsHistoryViewPagerAdapter

**getItem()**

```
  @Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    TabHistoryPopular tabHistoryPopular = new TabHistoryPopular();
    TabHistoryNew tabHistoryNew = new TabHistoryNew();
    TabHistoryCategory tabHistoryCategory = new TabHistoryCategory();
    TabHistoryFavorites tabHistoryFavorites = new TabHistoryFavorites();
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return tabHistoryPopular;
        case 1:
            return tabHistoryNew;
        case 2:
            return tabHistoryCategory;
        case 3:
            return tabHistoryFavorites;
    }
    return null;
}
```

### SlidingTabLayout (extends HorizontalScrollView)

**setViewPager(из FragmentHistory)**

```
    public void setViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    mTabStrip.removeAllViews();

    mViewPager = viewPager;
    if (viewPager != null) {
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new InternalViewPagerListener());
        populateTabStrip();
    }
}
```

**public void populateTabStrip()**

```
private void populateTabStrip() {
    final PagerAdapter adapter = mViewPager.getAdapter();
    final OnClickListener tabClickListener = new TabClickListener();

    for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
        View tabView = null;
        TextView tabTitleView = null;

        if (mTabViewLayoutId != 0) {
            // If there is a custom tab view layout id set, try and inflate it
            tabView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(mTabViewLayoutId, mTabStrip,
                    false);
            tabTitleView = (TextView) tabView.findViewById(mTabViewTextViewId);
        }

        if (tabView == null) {
            tabView = createDefaultTabView(getContext());
        }

        if (tabTitleView == null && TextView.class.isInstance(tabView)) {
            tabTitleView = (TextView) tabView;
        }

        if (mDistributeEvenly) {
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) tabView.getLayoutParams();
            lp.width = 0;
            lp.weight = 1;
        }

        tabTitleView.setText(adapter.getPageTitle(i));
        tabView.setOnClickListener(tabClickListener);
        String desc = mContentDescriptions.get(i, null);
        if (desc != null) {
            tabView.setContentDescription(desc);
        }

        mTabStrip.addView(tabView);
        if (i == mViewPager.getCurrentItem()) {
            tabView.setSelected(true);
        }
        tabTitleView.setTextColor(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.tab_selector));
        tabTitleView.setTextSize(14);
    }
}
```

Comment: Добавьте код, в котором происходят манипуляции с фрагментами.

Comment: @post_zeew по всей видимости у меня снова и снова создается popularFragment, их можно как то удалить?

Comment: Как минимум неправильно то, что в `getItem(...)` Вы независимо от позиции создаете все фрагменты, так делать не нужно.

Comment: @post_zeew Спасибо за совет, но проблема в другом.